Reasonable way to keycloak implement PEP in Java?
I am migrating an existing API running on Firebase integration to Keycloak, and I need some advice regarding the Policy Enforcement Point (PEP).
In the current scenario, I have a self-hosted Keycloak instance with authentication and authorization enabled.
I am using the Resource Owner Credentials flow for sign-in, which returns a JWT token. I have set up policies and permissions linked to resources like GET /users, GET /users/{id}, and applied scopes to these resources.
I have a Spring 3.x backend and need to enforce the authorization part, specifically the Policy Enforcement Point (PEP).
The first option would be to use Spring Security and manually set scopes on endpoints using @PreAuthorize
The second option would be to somehow import the file from Keycloak and automatically configure the setup, as described in this documentation https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_enforcer_overview, using the keycloak-policy-enforcer library in Java to load the file.
From what I understand, the exported JSON file contains the authorization mappings, which would be checked against the auth token sent in the request to validate permissions.
However, every time I change something in the Keycloak policies, I would need to update this file in my application. Is that correct?
I also noticed that the adapters are deprecated, so it seems like using keycloak-policy-enforcer is the recommended approach.


Reasonable way to keycloak implement PEP in Java?

No.
Problems with access control decisions taken on the authorization server
Access control is not the authorization server responsibility. As a reminder, the OAuth2 actors are respectively in charge of:

authorization server: authenticate resource owners (issue tokens), manage user data (roles & details), manage clients (allowed flows, scopes), and usually expose an API for resource servers to access user data
client: initiate authentication flows, store tokens, authorize requests to resource servers (set an access token as Authorization header)
resource server: provide secured access to REST resources. This includes access token validation and access control decisions. Using a policy enforcement service is no more than a delegation: the ultimate decision is still taken by the resource server based on the external service response.

When the resource server delegates access control to a policy service on the authorization server, there is a tight coupling between this authorization server and accessed resources. Your sample with a user resource is exceptional because authorization servers business is users - which is why it is usually also given the role of resource server for "users" (exposes a REST API, authorized with Bearer tokens, to manage users). But let's consider any other resource like a blog post: should the authorization server know what a Post entity is? Or even that it exists? Lets now imagine rules like "Can edit a post if has the moderator role or is the author of the post". This time, the authorization server has to know not only about the Post entity, but also how exactly it relates to users. It feels crazy to tighten an SSO that way to all the resources of all the applications using it.
Some more negative points:

calling the authorization server for access control decisions is as inefficient as introspection. These round trips from resource servers to the authorization server for each request introduce latency and can lead to an authorization server denial of service when the traffic and number of resource servers increase.
There is no real standard, which leads to the kind of compatibility issues you are facing when migrating from an authorization server to another.
You can hardly unit-test access control on authorization servers.
There is a risk that the access policies are not the same in all environments, or that the production rules are altered at some point in time.

Note that these considerations have nothing specific to the framework (Spring Security), the language (Java), or the authorization server (Keycloak).
Alternative: use Spring Security on resource servers
Stick with the 1st option you mention: use @PreAuthorize on the resource server(s). With this, you:

put access control where it belongs: the resource server already knows about the accessed resource internals, so there is no additional coupling
provided that the resource server is configured with a JWT decoder, that the access token is a JWT, and that its claims contain all the resource owner data needed to make the access decision (user roles, client scopes, audience, ...): permit or deny the request without a network call or database access
can unit test access control using mocked authentication instances
ship immutable access control rules with the jar (impossible to alter security at runtime with a malicious policy)

